# Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 print as pdf does not work

Tags: 13.04, gnome, printing, files, pdf

the function "print to file" doesn't have any output. 
I want to print for example a web page just as pdf. when the print dialogue is open, i select "print to file". a progress bar is displayed and finishes, but a pdf can't be found anywhere. 
my file manager is nautilus.

Comment: Try running `sudo updatedb` and then `locate <FILENAME>`. It will update the file database and then search your PC. Please respond with what you get.

Comment: acutally, there is no output, locate doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be more a workaround than an answer, but I think it is worth knowing so I post it here.

> *Notice* I know that the "official" point of view is that the PDF virtual printer is not needed any more thanks to the "print to file"
>   option. Nevertheless I still like the simmetry of having the virtual printer
>   --- you can set it as your default printer, use it with old programs that do not use the unified printing interface, etc. YMMV.

I often find that the option "print to file"can be quite flaky. The best method to print to PDF in my opinion is the following:

1) install a virtual PDF printer:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

2) Now you have a printer called "PDF" that you can choose.

3) Printing in that printer will result in a `.pdf` file in the folder `PDF` under your home directory. You may need to create it with `mkdir $HOME/PDF` (it's case-sensitive).

Advantages:

1) This is seen as a normal printer. ALL programs that can print can print to it, so you do not need the "print to file" option. For example you can easily do

```
ls -l | lpr -pPDF
```

and have a pdf file with the output of your command.

Caveats:

1) Move files from there because if you print a file multiple times the last version will  overwrite previous ones. This is avoidable with a little configuration file editing --- just open the file `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`, it is very well documented, and search for the line `#Label 0` and change it into `Label 1` (or 2 if it suits you better).

2) you do not decide the file name, and you need to move it where you want it. (It seems [it can be solved, but it's quite convoluted](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Installing_CUPS_Print_to_PDF_driver)).

3) Sometime upgrading the system disables the printer. Don't know why. Reinstalling `cups-pdf` solves the problem.

4) Color management and quality control is tricky.

Comment: it worked with cups, thx for the comprehensive answer! i tried to change the standard path in the configuration file in  /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf but it didn't work. well, is not such a big problem, would just be nice to change it.